# How do I scrape web comments that use a LiveFyre widget?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, livefyre

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape comments from various news articles. However, one site is using a LiveFyre widget so when I call:

```
test = soup.find(id="livefyre_comment_stream")
print test
```

I get:

```
<div id="livefyre_comment_stream"></div>
```

without all of the "stuff" in-between the div tags. I don't think I can use the LiveFyre API because this is not my site, and I'm not sure what my other options are. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose LiveFyre it using Ajax call to load contents so at the moment you scrape it results empty. If you are not using a direct call to the api you could make usage of another approach simulating the browser navigation (check Selenium Webdriver as example).

Comment: Responsible web apps often use JavaScript events to indicate their state. I Googled "Livefyre Javascript Events" to find that this is in fact true for Livefyre as well, http://answers.livefyre.com/developers/reference/javascript-events/#initialRenderComplete.